# Differences between Angular's $httpBackend expectPost and whenPost

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

While working on some tests, I was surprised to find, that simply changing the `$httpBackend.expectPost` to a `$httpBackend.whenPost` fixed some broken tests...

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend), it says that an `expect` "Creates a new request expectation.", while a `when` "Creates a new backend definition.".  Unfortunately this doesn't mean much too me...

Can someone explain the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#request-expectations-vs-backend-definitions),

> Request expectations provide a way to make assertions about requests
>   made by the application and to define responses for those requests.
>   The test will fail if the expected requests are not made or they are
>   made in the wrong order.
>
> Backend definitions allow you to define a fake backend for your
>   application which doesn't assert if a particular request was made or
>   not, it just returns a trained response if a request is made. The test
>   will pass whether or not the request gets made during testing.

With `whenPost()` definition, whenever your code makes a POST request through `$http`, this method will intercept and serve the response. But in case of `expectPost()`, it actually creates an expectation about POST request to that URL and if your code doesn't make any POST request to that URL, test will fail.
In case a request is made, then it will also respond with mock object.